# Make a checkbox check all checkboxes inside a ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

So, I'm trying to check all checkboxes (who is already separately working) using change event.

I have 2 methods, one for mark all the checkboxes, and one for deal with the checkboxes separately.

Here's my all checkboxes method:

```
validarCheckboxSelTodos(event){
  if (event.target.checked === true){
    this.checkboxSelTodos = true;
  } else {
    this.checkboxSelTodos = false;
  }
}
```

And here's my separated checkboxes code:

```
validarCheckbox(index: number, id: string, event, idTipoFolha: number){  
  if (event.target.checked === true || this.checkboxSelTodos === true){

    event.checked = true; //this is the only change that I made on this method, the rest of it is already working, but separately.
    
    this.checkbox = true;
    this.nfsSomar = this.matriculaEspecificada[index];
    this.idNota[index] = id;
    this.idTipoFolha = idTipoFolha;
    this.indexSomarSelecionado = index;
    console.log(this.idTipoFolha);
    console.log(this.nfs);
    } else {
      this.checkbox = false;
  }
```

My HTML:

```
<thead>
      <tr>
         <th style="width: 1%; text-align: center; margin-top: 5%;">
            <input (change)="validarCheckboxSelTodos($event)" id="selectodos" style="margin-right: 5%;" type="checkbox">
            Selecionar<br>todos
         </th>
         <th>Competência</th>
         <th>Matrícula</th>
         <th>Valor</th>
         <th>Nome</th>
         <th>CNPJ</th>
         <th>MEI Livre</th>
         <th>Situação</th>
         <th style="width: 10%">Detalhe</th>
      </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let col of matriculaEspecificada | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: m, id: 'second' }; let n = index;">
         <td class="text-center">
             <input (change)="validarCheckbox(((m - 1) * 10 + n), col.id, $event, col.idFolha)" id="selecao" type="checkbox">
         </td>
[...]
```

My idea was use the boolean `checkboxSelTodos` to trigger the `validarCheckbox` method, and then I set a validation on the `if` that verify if that variable was true, if so, then it will make the rest of it, including the new line that I add, `event.checked = true`.
My problem is that this `event.checked` is not working, is not marking all the other checkboxes.

Is there a possible solution for this using only the **change event**?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it like this: (I omitted your code from validarCheckbox, feel free to return it back if you think it is still useful)

```js
validarCheckboxSelTodos(event){
    for (let i = 0; i < this.matriculaEspecificada.length; i++) {
      this.matriculaEspecificada[i].isChecked = this.checkboxSelTodos;
    }
}

validarCheckbox(index: number, id: string, event, idTipoFolha: number){
     this.checkboxSelTodos = this.matriculaEspecificada.every((item: any) => {
        return item.isSelected == true;
     })
  }
```

```html
<thead>
      <tr>
         <th style="width: 1%; text-align: center; margin-top: 5%;">
            <input (change)="validarCheckboxSelTodos($event)" id="selectodos" style="margin-right: 5%;" [(ngModel)]="checkboxSelTodos" type="checkbox">
            Selecionar<br>todos
         </th>
         <th>Competência</th>
         <th>Mahttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/67821206/make-a-checkbox-check-all-checkboxes-inside-a-ngfor-angularts#trícula</th>
         <th>Valor</th>
         <th>Nome</th>
         <th>CNPJ</th>
         <th>MEI Livre</th>
         <th>Situação</th>
         <th style="width: 10%">Detalhe</th>
      </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let col of matriculaEspecificada | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: m, id: 'second' }; let n = index;">
         <td class="text-center">
             <input (change)="validarCheckbox(((m - 1) * 10 + n), col.id, $event, col.idFolha)" [(ngModel)]="col.isSelected" id="selecao" type="checkbox">
         </td>
[...]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for help. 
I'm trying to implement this, but the property "isChecked" can't be used with an array (I mean, matriculaEspecificada is an array with different atributes). 
Here's the error that I got: Property 'isChecked' does not exist on type 'Nfs'.
How can I solve it?

Comment: when you have you're array ready OnInit most likely, loop over it and add this property (isChecked) to every element in the array, and set it to false.
(this.matriculaEspecificada.forEach(e => e["isChecked"] = false);)
It is okay to add additional attributes on the front-end, even if you don't have them initially.

Comment: Can you make an more clear example? This array is a class with some attributes inside it. I didn't understood where exacly should I put the "isChecked" property. Also, can you take a look on the code again? I've made a correction that was wrong and though it would change something. It's on "validarCheckbox" method, specifically. Thanks for the help anyway!!